# Running a loop for each mysql query result fields

Tags: mysql, node.js

queryResultArr is the array that olds mysql queries results, let say i have in my table two columns: doc_1_hits and doc_2_hits, but i don't know prior how much docs i have and i want to run a loop like you can see below: queryResultsArr[0].doc_i_hits instead of doc_1_hits.

i tried a: var str = 'doc_'+i+'_hits'; and then  queryResultsArr[0].str but nothing..

```
for(var i = 1; i < 3; i++){
    if(queryResultsArr[0].doc_i_hits > 0 && queryResultsArr[1].doc_i_hits == 0){
        console.log(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could use the array notation and do it like below because they work similar in this case.

```
var a = 'doc_'+i+'_hits';
queryResultsArr[0][a]
```